# How to Implement External Website Authorization Login in an Office Add-in?

Tags: office-addins

I am developing an Office Word add-in, and the frontend is built with Vue.js 2. I am facing challenges while implementing the login functionality. My goal is to open the default browser and redirect users to my website when they click the login button on the add-in. If the user is already logged into my website, I want to redirect them directly to the authorization page. If the user is not logged in, I want them to log in first and then proceed to the authorization page.

I have referred to the implementation approach of the "IconScout" add-in, but I haven't been able to solve the problem. Are there any Vue.js 2 examples or suggestions for a similar feature?

The frontend of the add-in is developed using Vue.js 2.
The authorization page is hosted on my website.
The add-in needs to obtain relevant information after the user completes the authorization.